# CloudFront forwarding Custom Headers to Origin but with null Values

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I am using AWS EC2 for last couple of years. Now I want to enable HTTPS on my application developed in ASP. NET WEB API with front-end in AngularJS. For that I made a CloudFront distribution. It has successfully loaded the static files and called the REST API on EC2 hosted in IIS. But unfortunately the custom headers have **null** as a value when the requests came from CloudFront to my origin.

I have done the following relevant configurations on CloudFront distribution.

Following is my setting for custom origin headers. 
[image: origin]

Following is my setting for cache behaviors. 
[image: cache behav]

Further setting included the following:

- Whitelist Cookies: Authorization, VDName
- Query String Forwarding and Caching: Forward all, cache based on all
- Origin Protocol Policy: HTTP Only
- Viewer Protocol Policy: Redirect HTTP to HTTPS

My app has a login page where no *Authorization* is required. On successful  login the app sets three custom headers.

1. Authorization
2. x-working-company
3. x-working-branch

My app is successfully logging in the users but then logging them out automatically. So, To check this issue I wrote the following little code in my Authorization class to check the header values.

```
valToUpd.Add("S6", "CHK1");
valToUpd.Add("S7", "Before Null");
valToUpd.Add("S8", request.Headers.Count().ToString());
valToUpd.Add("S9", request.Headers.GetValues("Authorization").Single());
valToUpd.Add("S10", request.Headers.GetValues("x-working-company").Single());
valToUpd.Add("S11", request.Headers.GetValues("x-working-branch").Single());
var toUpdt = "";
if (request.Headers.Any(x => x.Key == "Authorization"))
    toUpdt = "A-";
if (request.Headers.Any(x => x.Key == "x-working-company"))
    toUpdt += "C-";
if (request.Headers.Any(x => x.Key == "x-working-branch"))
    toUpdt += "B-";
var ds = request.Headers.Where(x => x.Key == "x-working-branch").Select(c => c.Value);
toUpdt += " br val = ";
foreach (var item in ds)
{
    foreach (var i in item)
    {
        toUpdt += i + " - ";
    }
}
valToUpd.Add("S12", toUpdt);
usersHelperAdo.Update("Users", whereClause, valToUpd); // Its my DAL method to update values in Users table as per the where clause.
```

And as expected the CloudFront do forward the headers to my origin but with null values. The results are as follows:

[image: Database vals]

Following is the FireFox developer mode, where my front end is sending the request to CloudFront with all the custom headers with appropriate values. But then CloudFront is forwarding those headers to origin but making the values null.

[image: FireFox developer mode]

So, what am I doing wrong? Why CloudFront pass **null** as a value in my headers. Any help is highly appreciated. Many Thanks!

**EDIT**

I tried to hit the API's with Postman and following are the screenshots.

The following shows my call to the Login method and as expected it returns the Auth token with other custom headers set in the response.

[image: Postman Login]

I extracted the required headers from response and send another GET request and received the following.

[image: Postman GET call]

It throws 403 forbidden error. Its weird that in browser dev mode it throws 401 Unauthorized error and in Postman it is 403 Forbidden.

Any help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting *Origin Custom Headers* will have CloudFront include them in every request to your origin and if a header is already supplied it is overridden. This is not what you want and this explains why you see *null* values (you added your headers without values).

*Origin Custom Headers* should be used for constant values only or when you explicitly need to override a header.

In your case, you need to whitelist the headers in the *Cache Behavior Settings* by entering `x-working-branch` and `x-working-company` in the *Whitelist Headers* section and by clicking *Add Custom >>* as show here:

[image]

(I kept your *Authorization* and *Host* headers)

Please note that **forwarding headers impacts caching**: separate versions are created based on the header values. See also [Caching Content Based on Request Headers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html). This means that different combinations of `Authorization`, `Host`, `x-working-branch` and `x-working-company` will lead to different versions (this is obviously what you want here to avoid serving the same content to different users). This is also valid for query strings and cookies.

It is really important to understand how CloudFront caches objects. The most important part of the documentation is [Managing How Long Content Stays in an Edge Cache (Expiration)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html)

Comment: thanks for answering. I have added all 4 headers as suggested by you in whitelist and in Origin custom header there is only Content_type:application/json. 
I invalidated my distribution to clear cache. More over I am sending no-cache header to cache nothing for now. But same error is occurring. Any leads?

Comment: What is the _Status_ of your CloudFront distribution after the modifications? _Deployed_ or still _InProgress_? When you see _Deployed_ make sure to invalidate once more.

Comment: OK. let me do again. I am invalidating by entering /* in object path. is it the right way to clear all cache?

Comment: Yes and make sure that your modifications have been applied by looking at the _Status_ column in the console where you see all your distributions (you should see _Deployed_ there).

Comment: Nope. i think there is issue with caching behavior. So I thought to wait for 24 hrs so that cache may get clear and then I'll hit again. Otherwise I have scratched my head over it and passed 2 whole days but nothing helped. Thanks for your concern. I'll update you after hit

Comment: I tried to hit api with Postman too instead of browser. It log in the user, and when i extracted the headers and use them to call api methods, the cloudfront gave 403 error. the forbidden error was from cloudfront. can this information help us somewhere?

Comment: If you can share request/response headers, I could have a look.

Comment: I have edited the post with Postman request/response headers. Please have a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192350/discussion-between-awais-mahmood-and-jogold).

Comment: after long, it worked with your help. the issue was with cloudfront cache behaviors. Now all of my headers are in whitelist and none of them is in origin headers list. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AwaisMahmood how did u fix it? did u whitelist only those 4 headers or all of them?

Comment: @MaxySpark yes, i added all of my required headers into whitelist. and removed them from origin headers. moreover my cloudfront cached the error response. so need to clear that too before test.